# TaskCompletionSource : When to use SetResult() versus TrySetResult(), etc

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task-parallel-library, async-await, c#-5.0

I'm trying to wrap my head around the TPL, the new `async` / `await` features in C# 5, and the mysteries of `TaskCompletionSource`.

One thing that isn't clear to me is when to use `SetResult`, `SetException`, and `SetCancel` versus `TrySetResult`, `TrySetException` and `TrySetCancel`.

This is what MSDN has to say:

> This operation will return false if the Task is already in
>   one of the three final states: RanToCompletion, Faulted, or Canceled.
>
> This method also returns false if the underlying Task has
>   already been disposed.

Ok, I get that, but it doesn't really offer any guidance on when or why to use one over the other.

So, what's the deal?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

I *suspect* the point is that if there's only one thing which will be setting the result, just call `SetResult` etc. If you end up calling `SetResult` twice, that indicates a bug. (Likewise if the `TaskCompletionSource` has been disposed.)

If you've got several threads which could all be trying to set the result at the same time (e.g. it's there to indicate the first result out of several parallel  web service calls) then use `TrySetResult`, as it's entirely reasonable for multiple threads to "try" to set the result, unaware of whether another thread has already set it.

I've not seen any official guidance on it, but that would make sense.

Comment: i.e. Really, the only reason you'd need to call `TrySetResult` is if you set the result more than once.  `SetResult` "completes" the associated `Task` so calling `SetResult` again would be trying to set the `Task<T>`'s result after the task has completed. (`SetResult` blocks until the `Task` completes--as does `TrySetResult`)  If you only ever call `SetResult` once, then you should never need `TrySetResult`.  FWIW. `SetResult` chains to `TrySetResult`...

Comment: Thanks guys, you are making a lot of sense!

Comment: Also note that SetResult returns `void` while TrySetResult returns `bool` so if you want to conditionally do something depending on task state, then `TrySetResult` is both check and set at the same time (atomically?).

Answer (score 4):

In addition to Jon's answed, MS docs portal says regarding `TrySetResult`:

This operation will return false if the `Task<TResult>` is already in one of the three final states:

- **RanToCompletion**
- **Faulted**
- **Canceled**

link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskcompletionsource-1.trysetresult?view=net-5.0