# Async call within a lambda foreach is not awaited

Tags: c#, asynchronous, lambda, async-await, task-parallel-library

I have the following method that returns before it completes (method cut down for brevity):

```
private void ProcessAllItems(List<Item> items)
{
    items.ForEach(async item =>
    {
        var response = await Processor.IOBoundTaskAsync(item);
        // Some further processing on the response object.
    });
}
```

The Processor.IOBoundTaskAsync method returns a Task<SomeResponseObject>, so not a void.

So, what is happening?

I want the lambda foreach to process each item one at a time, so **not** in parallel.  For the first iteration, the code goes into the IOBoundTaskAsync and gets as far as the first "await" (where it calls the first of 4 awaited web service methods) and then the calling method "ProcessAllItems" exits.

I'm only using test data, so my list only has 1 item in it.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`List<T>.ForEach`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z(v=vs.110).aspx) converts your async lambda into `async void`, as it accepts an `Action<T>`. Although it does that and that has some complications with exception handling, your `ForEach` call should work properly. If not, you might not be using the async pattern correctly. I would advise you to set a breakpoint after the first `await` and see the continuation executing.

I would advise you to use a regular `foreach` instead:

```
private async Task ProcessAllItemsAsync(List<Item> items)
{
    foreach (var item in items)
    {
       var response = await Processor.IOBoundTaskAsync(item);
       // Some further processing on the response object.
    }
}
```

Read [How can I use Async with ForEach?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18667633/how-can-i-use-async-with-foreach) for more.