# .Net async ForEach() delegate throw task cancelled exception

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous

I have following c# code:

```
list.ForEach(async item =>
await doSomething(item));
```

and sometimes I am receiving TaskCancelledException.

Why this happens?

Comment: Don't do this. `List.ForEach()` isn't async-aware. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11564506/nesting-await-in-parallel-foreach) for more information on how to do this properly.

Comment: Or this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18667633/how-can-i-use-async-with-foreach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type of delegate inside `ForEach` is `Action<T>`

Return type of the `Action<T>` is `void` that means that yours `async item =>
await doSomething(item)` lambda translates into

`async void doSomething(T item)`. Using `async` with `void` means that it will be called asynchronously and not be awaited before next iteration happens.

You should always use `async` with `Task` return type.

In this example you should use usual `foreach`

so your example will looks like:

```
foreach(var item in list) 
{
  await doSomething(item);
}
```