# Adding items in Producer/Consumer pattern async using BlockingCollection

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task, producer-consumer

I'm following [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/collections/thread-safe/blockingcollection-overview) on `BlockingCollection` to implement a Producer/Consumer pattern but still can't get my tasks to execute in parallel on the producer side.

The problem is my `foreach` block is executing sequentially.  From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18667633/how-can-i-use-async-with-foreach), I understand that I have to *project* the collection of `PropertyLien<T>` as `Task`s.  How is that done?

```
// PropertyLien<T> is a class that models an asset (house/building/etc)
var googleAddresses = new BlockingCollection<Tuple<PropertyLien<string>, IEnumerable<GoogleAddress>>>()

// Consumer Threads
var consumer = Task.Run(() => {
    while(!googleAddresses.IsCompleted) {
        var adr = googleAddresses.Take();
        // Do work
    }

    Console.WriteLine("No more addresses to process");
});

// Producer Threads
var producer = Task.Factory.StartNew(async () => {
    // TODO: PROBLEM here, this is executing synchronously
    foreach(PropertyLien<string> property in properties) {
        try {
            // See: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Geocoding.net/
            await geocoder.GeocodeAsync(property.Address)
                .ContinueWith(task => {
                    var googResults = task.Result;
                    googleAddresses.Add(property, googResults);
                });
        }
        catch {}
    }
    googleAddresses.CompleteAdding();
});

// Need to wait for both tasks to complete.
Task.WaitAll(producer, consumer);
```

Comment: Don't `await geocoder.GeocodeAsync`. Instead put all tasks in a list (`yourList.Add(geocoder.GeocodeAsync(....))`) and then `await Task.WhenAll(yourList)`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Evk, this is the answer:

```
// Producer Threads
var producer = Task.Factory.StartNew(async () => {
    var tasks = properties.Select(property => {
        return geocoder.GeocodeAsync(property.Address)
            .ContinueWith(task => {
                // Do work
            });
    });

    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    googleAddresses.CompleteAdding();
});
```