# Process items from datagrid WPF one by one when use BackgroundWorker

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to process items one by one, every item from a datagrid element.

I have a method which creates a background worker:

```
internal void Run(Action doWork, Action completed, Action loadingBeforeAction = null, Action loadingAfterAction = null)
{
    using (BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker())
    {
        worker.DoWork += (s, ev) =>
        {
            if (loadingBeforeAction != null)
            {
                _dispatcher.Invoke(loadingBeforeAction);
            }

            doWork();
        };

        worker.RunWorkerCompleted += (s, ev) =>
        {
            if (loadingAfterAction != null)
            {
                _dispatcher.Invoke(loadingAfterAction);
            }

            completed();
        };

        worker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
}
```

And now process the selected items from datagrid:

```
var folders = btn.Name.Equals("test") 
    ? _model.Folders.ToArray()
    : fileDataGrid.SelectedItems.Cast<FolderStatus>().ToArray();"
```

and

```
foreach (var folder in folders)
{
    Run(() =>
    {
        Dispatcher.Invoke(()=> {_model.Message = $"This is message for {folder.Name}"});
        // long operation here
    }, () =>
    {
        // stuff
    }, () =>
     {
         _model.IsBusy = true;
     }, () =>
     {
         _model.IsBusy = false;
     });
}
```

Seems that all items are processed simultaneously and process message flick from text to other depends on `_model.Message` text.

How to process item one by one but without blocking the UI?

Comment: Why aren't you using tasks and async await? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18667633/how-can-i-use-async-with-foreach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BackgroundWorker` is a legacy component from Windows Forms. You shouldn't use it with WPF applications. It will work, but there are better ways to implement what you want.

The easiest way is to use the TAP (Task-based Asynchronous Programming) pattern, supported by the `async` and `await` C# keywords.

If you're targeting at least the .NET Framework 4.5 or .NET Core, you have everything out-of-the box. For .NET Framework 4.0, there are NuGet packages to enable this functionality.

The implementation could look like this:

```
async void MyButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var btn = (Button)sender;

    var folders = btn.Name.Equals("test") 
        ? _model.Folders.ToArray()
        : fileDataGrid.SelectedItems.Cast<FolderStatus>().ToArray();"

    foreach (var folder in folders)
    {
        // This will be executed on the UI thread
        _model.Message = $"This is message for {folder.Name}"};
        _model.IsBusy = true;

        // This will be executed on a worker thread due to Task.Run
        await Task.Run(() => YourLongRunningOperation(folder));

        await Task.Run(() => SomeOtherLongRunningOperation());

        // This will be executed again on the UI thread
        _model.IsBusy = false;
    }
}
```

A couple of notes:

- The method above has a signature `async void (object, EventArgs)`. However, `async` methods should return a `Task` or a `Task<T>`. `async void` is here to make the event handler `async`. This is the only case when you should use `async void` - UI event handlers. Note that an uncaught exception in an `async void` UI event handler will crash your application.
- When `await Task.Run()` returns, the thread context will be restored to the original one. So, your `_model.IsBusy = false` code will be executed on the UI thread again. If you don't need this, use `await Task.Run().ConfigureAwait(false)`.

Read more about the [Task-based asynchronous pattern (TAP)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/task-based-asynchronous-pattern-tap).

Here is a [short but nice FAQ and tutorial](https://igorpopov.io/2018/06/30/asynchronous-programming-in-csharp/) too.

Comment: About that task await, I cannot change `_model.IsBusy` (means nothing happens on UI side) inside `Task.Run` even if I use `Dispatcher.Invoke`... That's reason I used `BackgroundWorker`

Comment: @SnakeEyes, don't use `Dispatcher.Invoke` inside `Task.Run`. The sample I provided should work as-is. If it doesn't, there is something wrong in your other code.

Comment: I did like: `Loaded += DoLoad;` and `async void DoLoad(...) { await Task.Run(()=> { _model.IsBusy = false; });`, nothing happens

Comment: @SnakeEyes, no, this is wrong. Don't set `_model.IsBusy` inside `Task.Run`. Did you carefully read my answer? Please just copy-paste the method I provided and replace `YourLongRunningOperation` with your method.