# ForEach() gives "A second operation started on this context before a previous operation completed". foreach loop does not

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have the following model and claims:

```cs
var bm = new UserProfileUpdateModel
{
  LastName = "new",
  FirstName = "name",
};

List<Claim> claims = new List<Claim>
{
    new Claim("family_name", bm.LastName),
    new Claim("given_name", bm.FirstName),
};
```

In the .NET Core 3.1 application, I am going to remove all the matched claims using `_userManager.RemoveClaimsAsync()` first and then add the new corresponding claim in `claims` using `_userManager.AddClaimAsync()`.

### Problem:

When I trying to loop the items in `claims` and do the remove/add, it works.

```cs
foreach(var c in claims)
{
    // principal is a ClaimsPrincipal
    var list = principal.Claims.Where(currC => currC.Type == c.Type).ToList();
    var removeResult = await _userManager.RemoveClaimsAsync(user, list);
    if(removeResult.Succeeded)
    {
        var addResult = await _userManager.AddClaimAsync(user, c);
    }
}
```

However, when I switched to use `ForEach()`,

```cs
claims.ForEach(async c =>
{
    // principal is a ClaimsPrincipal
    var list = principal.Claims.Where(currC => currC.Type == c.Type).ToList();
    var removeResult = await _userManager.RemoveClaimsAsync(user, list);
    if(removeResult.Succeeded)
    {
        var addResult = await _userManager.AddClaimAsync(user, c);
    }
});
```

The application will throw an exception telling me `A second operation started on this context before a previous operation completed`.

[image: exception in visual studio]

So the question is, **what happened when I call `foreach()` and `ForEach()`? And why only `ForEach()` will cause the exception?**

Comment: General advice: don't use `ForEach`. I'm not sure why it was ever included in the first place, but there's almost never a good reason to use it.

Comment: You're creating an `async` lambda. The `ForEach` is just creating the lambdas - not waiting for each to finish before running the next iteration.

Comment: @DavidG Agreed, should have been left out of .NET Core. It's unfortunate Microsoft keeps adding backwards compatibility to 20 years old code

Comment: Pretty much a dupe of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18667633/how-can-i-use-async-with-foreach

Comment: Thank you @Damien_The_Unbeliever I see what you mean. So basically `ForEach()` is a trap when doing async call haha.