# Implementing a pool with a time limit

Tags: c#, multithreading, pool

Continuing from this question:

[Correct way to implement a resource pool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29501285/correct-way-to-implement-a-resource-pool)

I'm now thinking about implementing a maximum amount of time that a user of the pool is allowed to continue to hold on to an object from the pool, but I'm not sure of the right way to implement such a thing. So, say we have something like this:

```
IFoo GetFooFromPool()
{
    if (_sem.Wait(WaitTimeOut))
    {
        return Pop();
    }
    throw new WaitTimeoutException("Timed out waiting for Foo instance");
}
```

So `_sem` is a semaphore and `Pop` will pop off an instance from the stack (initializing it if needed), so far so good.

When the caller is done with the `IFoo`, the return it to the stack like so:

```
void ReleaseFoo(IFoo p)
{
    if (p == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("Foo parameter is null");
    }
    Push(p);
    _sem.Release();
}
```

And I actually wrap all this up with a wrapper class using `IDisposable` to ensure that the `Foo` gets returned to the pool. So from the client side, it looks something like this:

```
using (var f = myPool.GetDisposableFoo())
{
    // Do stuff...
}
```

What I'd like to do is have it such that if `// Do Stuff` takes too long (or likely hangs), the `IFoo` will get recycled and the calling code will throw an exception.

So I thought of doing something like this:

```
private IFoo Pop()
{
    IFoo p;
    _stack.TryPop(out p);
    if (p == null)
    {
        p = RunFactory();   // this is lazy initialization of the stack
    }
    if (MaximumLoanTime > 0)
    {
        p.CurrentToken = new CancellationTokenSource();
        Task.Delay(MaximumLoanTime, p.CurrentToken.Token).ContinueWith(() =>
        {
            // Timeout, return to the stack
            // Inform current owner???
            Push(p);
        });
    }
    return p;
}
```

The problem is how to make sure that the current holder gets signaled so that it doesn't continue to try and use the instance of `IFoo` that might now be in use by somebody else.

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up adding a `LoanExpired` event and an `OnLoanExpired` method to my `IFoo`. So now it works like this:

```
private IFoo Pop()
{
    IFoo p;
    _stack.TryPop(out p);
    if (p == null)
    {
        p = RunFactory();   // this is lazy initialization of the stack
    }
    if (MaximumLoanTime > 0)
    {
        p.CurrentToken = new CancellationTokenSource();
        Task.Delay(MaximumLoanTime, p.CurrentToken.Token).ContinueWith(() =>
        {
                p.CurrentToken.Dispose();
                p.OnLoanExpired();
        }, TaskContinuationOptions.NotOnCanceled);
    }
    return p;
}
```

Returning the expired loan object is now deferred to my `FooWrapper` which subscribes to the `LoanExpired` event of the `Foo` instance that it's wrapping:

```
private void foo_LoanExpired(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    isDisposed = true;    // this is checked on any attempt to use this object
    foo.LoanExpired -= foo_LoanExpired;     
    _pool.ReturnExpiredLoan(foo);
    OnLoanExpired();                                // pass event up to any client handlers
}
```

And back in my pool, `ReturnExpiredLoan` looks like this:

```
void ReturnExpiredLoan(IFoo p)
{
    // Since it's expired, there is a risk it is broken or hung up
    // so we push null back on the stack to force a fresh instance next time around
    _stack.Push(null);
    _sem.Release();

    p.Dispose();
}
```

Now I made the decision to actually just dump the expired `Foo` and create a new one in my particular case, but that wouldn't necessarily be the right approach for a different resource.

And a couple of other changes, when my `FooWrapper` is disposed, I have to unsubscribe the event handler:

```
public void Dispose()
{
    foo.LoanExpired -= foo_LoanExpired;
    if (!isDisposed)        // don't try and return an instance if it was killed already
    {
        _pool.ReleaseFoo(foo);
    }
}
```

And when I push my `Foo` back on the stack, I need to cancel the expiration and dispose the token source:

```
private void Push(IFoo p)
{
    if (p.CurrentToken != null)
    {
        p.CurrentToken.Cancel();
        p.CurrentToken.Dispose();
        p.CurrentToken = null;
    }
    _stack.Push(p);
}
```