# C# await process exits without exception

Tags: c#, .net, parallel-processing, async-await, task-parallel-library

I have a scenario where I have to run list of students in parallel/independently once I get list of students. However when I run those with following kinda code, program ends without completing properly.

```
public async Task ProcessStudents()
{
    var students = await GetStudentsAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    ProcessSingleStudent(students);
}

private static ProcessSingleStudent(IEnumerable<StudentModel> students)
{
    students.ForEach(async student =>
    {
         await ValidateSingleStudentAsync(student).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}

private async Task ValidateSingleStudentAsync(StudentModel student)
{
     //Do some validations here
     if(validate)
     {
       var updated =  await UpdateStudentAsync(student).configureAwait(false); //<== This cause issue
     }
}
```

As I see `UpdateStudentAsync` causing issue, that if go with `F10` this method doesn't return anything and console app stops. Even I put every call in `try-catch` I couldn't find anything. If I step in each debug point, I get expected result.

Unable to understand where is the issue.

Comment: Where is the code for `UpdateStudentAsync`?

Comment: Please, share the code where `ValidateSingleStudentAsync` is invoked and give us more information about the main application, it means: Is running on Windows Form App or Console App, if `ValidateSingleStudentAsync`` is running into a temporary context, etc

Comment: This is what you need https://stackoverflow.com/a/39174582/782754

Answer (score 1):

Your ProcessSingleStudent doesn't await the results of each call in the foreach.  So it terminates after iterating

You want something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15136833/8302901

Comment: You were right, instead of running asynchronous method in foreach, I am adding returning task into a task list and then passing that task list to `Task.WhenAll()`

Answer (score 0):

Remember that async-await is contagious or *ProcessSingleStudent* method is not itself async, it's synchronous. What you need is something like

```
private async Task ProcessSingleStudent(IEnumerable<StudentModel> students)
{
    await students.ForEach(async student =>
    {
         await ValidateSingleStudentAsync(student).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }).ConfigureAwait(false)
}
```

But this is not possible (it doesn't compile) without a little bit of help of a library named [AsyncEnumerator](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AsyncEnumerator/1.1.0).

The code becomes

```
private async Task ProcessSingleStudent(IEnumerable<StudentModel> students)
    {
        await students.ParallelForEachAsync(async student =>
        {
             await ValidateSingleStudentAsync(student).ConfigureAwait(false);
        },
         maxDegreeOfParalellism: 30,
         cancellationToken: null,
         breakLoopOnException: true
        ).ConfigureAwait(false)
    }
```

Comment: I don't think first block of code is possible to add await on `ForEach` method.

Comment: Is not, I said that. Maybe I didn't make myself clear about it.