# Without blocking UI using async and await

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, async-await, parallel.foreach

My requirement is, need to render all framework elements which are bound with data using async and await.

Tried below possibilities:

> 1. If i am using `asyncmethod().result` it will block the UI and it
>      will be waiting for a long time to completion.
> 2. If I am using await keyword the **controlstoconfigure foreach(2nd
>          one)** will be hit for before completion of **parallel.foreach()**

So can you please suggest me for rendering elements, call the 2nd for each after completion of **parallel foreach** or **without blocking UI**?

Code snippet:

1)Renderingwidget - this method is used to get framework elements in the collection which is bound with data.

2)FetchData - this method is used to get the data from the server for particular framework element.

3)GetTablefromserver - this method is used to get the data based on queries.

```
    public async void RenderingWidget()
    {
        ConcurrentDictionary<string, EngineChangedEventArgs> controlsToConfigure = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, EngineChangedEventArgs>();
        foreach (var engines in MainWindow.ViewModel.RelationalDataManagerList.Values)
        {
            Dictionary<string, FrameworkElement> controlcollection = CurrentDashboardReport.WidgetCollection;
            Parallel.ForEach(controlcollection, async item =>
             {
                 try
                 {
                     try
                     {
                         controlsToConfigure.TryAdd(item.Key, await FetchDataInParallel(MainWindow.ViewModel.RelationalDashboardReportList[engines.DataSourceName].Reports, item.Key,));
                     }
                     catch (Exception ex)
                     {
                         ExceptionLog.WriteExceptionLog(ex, null);
                         throw new ParallelException(ex, item.Key);
                     }
                 }
                 catch (ParallelException ex)
                 {
                     exceptions.Enqueue(ex);
                     ExceptionLog.WriteExceptionLog(ex, GeneratedQueryText);
                 }
             });
            if (exceptions.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (var nonRenderedControls in exceptions)
                {
                    controlsToConfigure.TryAdd(nonRenderedControls.ReportName, await FetchDataInParallel(CurrentDashboardReport.Reports, nonRenderedControls.ReportName));
                }
            }
        }
        foreach (var control in controlsToConfigure)
        {
            (CurrentDashboardReport.WidgetCollection[control.Key] as DashboardDataControl).CurrentDashboardReport.OnActiveColumnsChanged(control.Value);                   
        }
    }

    public async Task<EngineChangedEventArgs> FetchDataInParallel(RelationalReportCollection reports, string myReport)
    {
        var dataTable = await GetTableFromServer(reports.Query);
        eventArgs = new EngineChangedEventArgs
        {
            ItemsSource = dataTable
        };
        return eventArgs;
    }

    public async Task<DataTable> GetTableFromServer(string query)
    {
        var resultTable = new DataTable
        {
            Locale = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
        };
        SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, sqlConnection)
        SqlDataReader dataReader = null;
        try
        {
            if (sqlConnection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                sqlConnection.Open();
            }
            dataReader =await command.ExecuteReaderAsync();
            resultTable.Load(dataReader);
            return resultTable;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (dataReader != null)
            {
                dataReader.Dispose();
            }
            command.Dispose();
            return resultTable;
        }
    }
```

Comment: 1) asyncmethod().result run in sync mode.  2) async item =>, but where await?

Comment: Parellel.Foreach will not work well  with async-await. refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/dataflow-task-parallel-library

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11564506/nesting-await-in-parallel-foreach

Comment: @WPFUser Cool. I didn't know this too. Thnxs.)

Comment: @WPFUser, please find below link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15136542/parallel-foreach-with-asynchronous-lambda

Comment: @Dmitriy, await keyword is present in the try block of controlsToConfigure.TryAdd() line

Comment: @Pandi Yeah, I see.

Comment: Parallel.ForEach itself is blocking.

Comment: No @mm8, parallelForeach is working fine.If i put result keyword it will block the UI(Already know about result keyword which is run in synchronous).

Comment: What is your question...?

Comment: My question is what i will do for calling the 2nd foreach after completion of parallel foreach?

Comment: "Second" foreach is foreach (var nonRenderedControls in exceptions) ?

Comment: No.(var control in controlsToConfigure).

Comment: Did you read this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11564506/nesting-await-in-parallel-foreach

Answer (score 2):

`Parallel.ForEach` doesn't play well with `async`/`await` as you release the thread for the duration of the `async` call. Please refer to the following question for more information about this: [Nesting await in Parallel.ForEach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11564506/nesting-await-in-parallel-foreach)

You may just call `Parallel.ForEach` on a thread pool thread and then use the `Task.WhenAll` method to wait until all tasks have completed Before you continue:

```
public async void RenderingWidget()
{
    ConcurrentDictionary<string, EngineChangedEventArgs> controlsToConfigure = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, EngineChangedEventArgs>();

    List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();

    foreach (var engines in MainWindow.ViewModel.RelationalDataManagerList.Values)
    {
        Dictionary<string, FrameworkElement> controlcollection = CurrentDashboardReport.WidgetCollection;
        tasks.Add(Task.Run(() =>
        {
            Parallel.ForEach(controlcollection, item =>
            {
                try
                {
                    try
                    {
                        controlsToConfigure.TryAdd(item.Key, FetchDataInParallel(MainWindow.ViewModel.RelationalDashboardReportList[engines.DataSourceName].Reports, item.Key).Result);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        ExceptionLog.WriteExceptionLog(ex, null);
                        throw new ParallelException(ex, item.Key);
                    }
                }
                catch (ParallelException ex)
                {
                    exceptions.Enqueue(ex);
                    ExceptionLog.WriteExceptionLog(ex, GeneratedQueryText);
                }
            });
            if (exceptions.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (var nonRenderedControls in exceptions)
                {
                    controlsToConfigure.TryAdd(nonRenderedControls.ReportName, FetchDataInParallel(CurrentDashboardReport.Reports, nonRenderedControls.ReportName).Result);
                }
            }
        }));
    }

    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

    foreach (var control in controlsToConfigure)
    {
        (CurrentDashboardReport.WidgetCollection[control.Key] as DashboardDataControl).CurrentDashboardReport.OnActiveColumnsChanged(control.Value);
    }
}

public async Task<EngineChangedEventArgs> FetchDataInParallel(RelationalReportCollection reports, string myReport)
{
    var dataTable = await GetTableFromServer(reports.Query).ConfigureAwait(false);
    return new EngineChangedEventArgs
    {
        ItemsSource = dataTable
    };
}
```

Comment: In My code FetchData method is declared as Async method and which is returned a task.This method is used in various places.May i know how to resolve this? If i remove the async it will be act as synchronous

Comment: Don't  use Parallel.ForEach or block, for example using the Result property. This should be safe if you call ConfigureAwait(false) in the FetchDataInParallel (which you should do in "service" methods).

Comment: Please remember to accept the answer if your issue has been solved.

Comment: While run source If i use .Result in fetchdata method, it will not go to next line. It will wait for long time to completion.

Comment: Where does it block?