# how to loop through rest api without too many requests using httpClient

Tags: c#, asynchronous, while-loop, async-await

I'm kinda new to async and await. Whenever I call API repeatedly I get a too many request error. So my question is who do I loop through an API call using Async and Await so I don't get penalized? See following code example.

```
Task <IDList> ListOfIDs = new Task(GetIDListAsycn);
var result  = ListOfIDs.Wait()
```

Once I get the results, I want to loop through them and get the ID to pass to the API URL like this until I ran out of IDs:

```
foreach(var n in List) { client.BaseUrl (new Uri("http://api/users/n.ID"))};
```

Problem is like I said whenever I attempt this kind of logic I get too many request because the client.GetStringAsync is called so many times in short period of time.

Comment: await Task.Delay

Comment: The best way is to create a class with one function which does your basic operation. Create a new instance of that class in your for loop and call that method.

Comment: It's still gonna be the same result , you're still looping through that

Comment: who is developing that API? Is it you? If yes then create API which comma separated ids and return the list of object

Comment: Hi Ricky, no I'm not the one creating the API this is from Zoom, I just can't figure out how to loop through it without hitting the "too many request error" somehow I need to iterate thru the Id as a parameter for the api url if that make sense

Answer (score 4):

As [@JuanR](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4190402/juanr) mentioned, the issue rises where too many requests are sent to the API faster than they could be handled.

To overcome this issue and have more control over sending requests, I can think of two approaches:

### Using an `async` Method

You can define `GetItemsByID` as `async` and wait for the response to each request before  proceeding to send the next one.

```
private static async Task GetItemsAsync(List<dynamic> list)
{
    var client = new HttpClient();

    foreach (var n in list)
    {
        var res = await client.GetAsync("http://api/users/" + n.ID);

        // Do whatever you want with `res` here
    }
}
```

#### Calling the async method

- Call it inside an `async` method like this:

```
await GetItemsAsync(List);
```

- Call it inside a non-`async` method:

```
GetItemsAsync(List).Wait();
```

---

### More Control using `ActionBlock`

You can use `ActionBlock` so that multiple calls to the API at the same time "could" make the whole process faster. It is possible to limit the number of parallel calls using `MaxDegreeOfParallelism`:

```
private static void GetItemsByID(List<dynamic> list)
{
    var client = new HttpClient();
    var workerBlock = new ActionBlock<string>(async id =>
        {
            var res = await client.GetAsync("http://api/users/" + id);

            // Do whatever you want with `res` here
        },
        new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4 }
    );

    foreach (var n in list)
    {
        workerBlock.Post(n.ID);
    }
    workerBlock.Complete();

    // Wait for all messages to propagate through the network.
    workerBlock.Completion.Wait();
}
```

#### Calling the method

- Call it simply like any other method:

```
GetItemsById(List);
```

---

### Read More

- [ActionBlock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.actionblock-1)

Comment: The `Parallel.ForEach` [is not async-friendly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15136542/parallel-foreach-with-asynchronous-lambda). The lambda passed is [async void](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming#avoid-async-void). This is a very common mistake. Be careful when you pass an async delegate to a lambda. If the parameter is a `Func<Task>` it's OK. If the parameter is a simple `Action`, the method is not designed with async in mind.

Comment: Thanks @theodorZoulias for bringing that to my attention. Missed that part completely!

Comment: Great use case for the TPL Dataflow library! I would probably prefer to make the `GetItemsByID` method asynchronous (return `Task` instead of void), and return the `workerBlock.Completion` to the caller so that it can be awaited asynchronously.

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is at the loop level. The loop is executing too fast, sending a lot of calls to the API, which causes the server to complain about too many requests.

You need to throttle it by slowing down the calls:

```
foreach(var n in List) 
{ 
    client.BaseUrl(new Uri("http://api/users/" + n.ID));

    //Add this to make the thread sleep for a second.
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
```

Change the milliseconds to whatever works for you.

Comment: At this point, I don't think I have any other choice but to use delay or sleep, in any which way I see it, it looks like I will have to repeat the calls to API no matter what. It's not an Async Await issue it's the calls that I make repeatedly. Thank y'all.

Comment: @PinoyDev: Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted if it helped you solve your issue. :-)

Comment: unfortunately, I'm still hitting the limit thank you for your help

Comment: @PinoyDev: Slow it down even more. If not, there may be other types of restrictions on the API.

Comment: @JuanR I got your problem please specify the limitation on API call or share the link so that I can provide you with the optimized solution

Comment: Hi Ricky, its 10 request per second I believe.