# Avoiding await in foreach loop

Tags: c#, .net, performance, async-await

I am trying to optimize this code to decrease the time taken to complete the `for`loop. In this case, `CreateNotification()` takes a long time and using `async` `await` does not improve performance as each asynchronous call is being awaited. I would like to use `Task.WhenAll()` to optimize the code. How can I do this?

```
foreach (var notification in notificationsInput.Notifications)
{
  try
  {
    var result = await CreateNotification(notification);
    notification.Result = result;          
  }
  catch (Exception exception)
  {
    notification.Result = null;
  }
  notifications.Add(notification);
}
```

Comment: what your CreatNotification do and what is `context`

Comment: You can probably use [Parallel.ForEach](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach.aspx) instead.

Comment: CreateNotification is a lambda function. CreateNotification calls an endpoint to create a notification. i have edited the code to remove context

Comment: @Leandro That doesn't really play so nicely with async methods :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15136542/parallel-foreach-with-asynchronous-lambda

Comment: just curious, if number of notifications is not big simply using thread pool is good idea or not!

Comment: @Amit But a task doesn't necessarily mean a thread :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can call `Select` on the collection whose elements you want to process in parallel, passing an asynchronous delegate to it. This asynchronous delegate would return a `Task` for each element that's processed, so you could then call `Task.WhenAll` on all these tasks. The pattern is like so:

```
var tasks = collection.Select(async (x) => await ProcessAsync(x));
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

For your example:

```
var tasks = notificationsInput.Notifications.Select(async (notification) =>
{
    try
    {
        var result = await CreateNotification(notification);
        notification.Result = result;          
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        notification.Result = null;
    }
});
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

This assumes that `CreateNotification` is thread-safe.

Comment: Does this execute in parallel? I think this still executes asynchronously.

Comment: @DavidB: The asynchronous tasks will execute in parallel. At the `await` keyword, control will be returned to the caller; thus, the `Select` would continue iterating over the rest of the notifications whilst the previous `CreateNotification` tasks are still in flight.

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

You will need to install DataFlow to use this solution

https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow/

---

Depending on what `CreateNotification` is and whether you want to run this in parallel.

You could use a DataFlow `ActionBlock`, it will give you the best of both worlds if this is *IO bound* or Mix *IO/CPU bound* operations and let you run `async` and in parallel

```
public static async Task DoWorkLoads(NotificationsInput notificationsInput)
{
   var options = new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
                     {
                        MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 50
                     };

   var block = new ActionBlock<Something>(MyMethodAsync, options);

   foreach (var notification in notificationsInput.Notifications)
      block.Post(notification);

   block.Complete();
   await block.Completion;

}

...

public async Task MyMethodAsync(Notification notification)
{       
     var result = await CreateNotification(notification);
     notification.Result = result;    
}
```

Add pepper and salt to taste.

Answer (score 1):

I think this ought to be equivalent to your code:

```
var notifications = new ConcurrentBag<Notification>();
var tasks = new List<Task>();
foreach (var notification in notificationsInput.Notifications)
{
    var task = CreateNotification(notification)
                    .ContinueWith(t =>
                    {
                        if (t.Exception != null)
                        {
                            notification.Result = null;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            notification.Result = t.Result;
                        }
                        notifications.Add(notification);
                    });
    tasks.Add(task);
}
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

`.ContinueWith(` will receive the completed/failed task from `CreateNotification(`, and is itself a task. We add the `ContinueWith` task to a list and use that in the `WhenAll(`.

I'm using a `ConcurrentBag` for notifications so that you can add from multiple threads safely. If you want to turn this into a regular list, you can call `var regularListNotifications = notifications.ToList();` (assuming you have a using for LINQ).