# UWP Performance issue and UI Update - Foreach vs. WaitAll

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, task

In my previous question I was not able to report UI changes in a loop. ([UWP - Perform long view model creation and keep UI responsive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58793118/uwp-perform-long-view-model-creation-and-keep-ui-responsive))
Thanks to the help now I'm able to show the changes in the loop using await Task.Run() but I've found an additional method that is the WhenAll().

So here the second round of test, I've added 3 text boxes to calculate the duration of the loop and also I've duplicated all to check ForEach versus the Async version.

In debug mode the difference is quite impressive (debug mode):

```
        private int maxProperties = 1000;
        private int maxSubItems = 100;
```

ForEach: 3037.0374 ms

ForEachAsync: 2258.7025 ms

difference: -778.3349 ms

```
        private int maxProperties = 2000;
        private int maxSubItems = 200;
```

ForEach: 22233.6575 ms

ForEachAsync: 12028.2828 ms

difference: -10205.3747 ms

As my effective numbers are above those the advantage is relevant BUT again the scroll bar does not fill nice... it jumps.
Am I doing something wrong again?

(I've checked and in UWP I've not found a InvokeRequired on the object to swap threads to do the update...)

**App.xaml.cs** 
as above

**MainPage.xaml**

```
<Page
    x:Class="TestLoadSync.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="using:TestLoadSync"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid>
        <Button
            Width="296"
            Height="143"
            Margin="245,214,0,0"
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            Click="Button_Click"
            Content="Button" />
        <ProgressBar
            x:Name="ProgB"
            Width="296"
            Height="82"
            Margin="245,82,0,0"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        <TextBox
            x:Name="startT"
            Width="296"
            Height="44"
            Margin="245,412,0,0"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            Text="TextBox"
            TextWrapping="Wrap" />
        <TextBox
            x:Name="endT"
            Width="296"
            Height="44"
            Margin="309,456,0,0"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            Text="TextBox"
            TextWrapping="Wrap" />
        <TextBox
            x:Name="diffT"
            Width="296"
            Height="44"
            Margin="161,500,0,0"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            Text="TextBox"
            TextWrapping="Wrap" />
        <Button
            x:Name="Button2"
            Width="296"
            Height="143"
            Margin="694,214,0,0"
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            Click="Button2_Click"
            Content="Button2" />
        <ProgressBar
            x:Name="ProgB2"
            Width="296"
            Height="82"
            Margin="694,82,0,0"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        <TextBox
            x:Name="startT2"
            Width="296"
            Height="44"
            Margin="694,412,0,0"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            Text="TextBox"
            TextWrapping="Wrap" />
        <TextBox
            x:Name="endT2"
            Width="296"
            Height="44"
            Margin="758,456,0,0"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            Text="TextBox"
            TextWrapping="Wrap" />
        <TextBox
            x:Name="diffT2"
            Width="296"
            Height="44"
            Margin="610,500,0,0"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            Text="TextBox"
            TextWrapping="Wrap" />
        <TextBox
            x:Name="diffT3"
            Width="296"
            Height="44"
            Margin="454,584,0,0"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            Text="TextBox"
            TextWrapping="Wrap" />

    </Grid>
</Page>
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;

// The Blank Page item template is documented at https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=402352&clcid=0x409

namespace TestLoadSync
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        private ObservableCollection<PropertyViewModel> _PropVM;
        public MainPage()
        {
            DataLayer aDAL = new DataLayer();
            _PropVM = new ObservableCollection<PropertyViewModel>();
            this.InitializeComponent();
            ProgB.Maximum = 1;
            aDAL.loadData();
            //Debug.WriteLine(((App)App.Current)._Properties.Count());
            //Debug.WriteLine(((App)App.Current)._ImagesHirerachy.Count());
        }

        private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            _PropVM.Clear();
            System.GC.Collect();

            DateTime aSt, aEt;
            aSt = DateTime.Now;
            startT.Text = aSt.ToString();
            ProgB.Value = 0;
            ProgB.Maximum = ((App)App.Current)._Properties.Count() + 1;
            foreach (PropertyModel aProperty in ((App)App.Current)._Properties)
            {
                ProgB.Value++;
                await Task.Run(() => _PropVM.Add(new PropertyViewModel(aProperty)));
            }
            ProgB.Value = ProgB.Maximum;
            aEt = DateTime.Now;
            endT.Text = aEt.ToString();
            diffT.Text = aEt.Subtract(aSt).TotalMilliseconds.ToString();
        }
        private async void Button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            _PropVM.Clear();
            System.GC.Collect();

            DateTime aSt, aEt;
            aSt = DateTime.Now;
            startT2.Text = aSt.ToString();
            ProgB2.Value = 0;
            ProgB2.Maximum = ((App)App.Current)._Properties.Count() + 1;
            await ((App)App.Current)._Properties.ForEachAsyncConcurrent(async (aProperty) =>
            {
                await Task.Run(() => _PropVM.Add(new PropertyViewModel(aProperty)));
                ProgB2.Value++;
            });
            ProgB2.Value = ProgB2.Maximum;
            aEt = DateTime.Now;
            endT2.Text = aEt.ToString();
            diffT2.Text = aEt.Subtract(aSt).TotalMilliseconds.ToString();
            if (diffT.Text != "")
            {
                diffT3.Text = (Convert.ToDouble(diffT2.Text) - Convert.ToDouble(diffT.Text)).ToString();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Add a class file to project and call it:
**AsyncEx.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TestLoadSync
{
    static class AsyncEx
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Concurrently Executes async actions for each item of <see cref="IEnumerable<typeparamref name="T"/>
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T">Type of IEnumerable</typeparam>
        /// <param name="enumerable">instance of <see cref="IEnumerable<typeparamref name="T"/>"/></param>
        /// <param name="action">an async <see cref="Action" /> to execute</param>
        /// <param name="maxDegreeOfParallelism">Optional, An integer that represents the maximum degree of parallelism,
        /// Must be grater than 0</param>
        /// <returns>A Task representing an async operation</returns>
        /// <exception cref="ArgumentOutOfRangeException">If the maxActionsToRunInParallel is less than 1</exception>
        public static async Task ForEachAsyncConcurrent<T>(
            this IEnumerable<T> enumerable,
            Func<T, Task> action,
            int? maxDegreeOfParallelism = null)
        {
            if (maxDegreeOfParallelism.HasValue)
            {
                using (var semaphoreSlim = new SemaphoreSlim(
                    maxDegreeOfParallelism.Value, maxDegreeOfParallelism.Value))
                {
                    var tasksWithThrottler = new List<Task>();

                    foreach (var item in enumerable)
                    {
                        // Increment the number of currently running tasks and wait if they are more than limit.
                        await semaphoreSlim.WaitAsync();

                        tasksWithThrottler.Add(Task.Run(async () =>
                        {
                            await action(item).ContinueWith(res =>
                            {
                                // action is completed, so decrement the number of currently running tasks
                                semaphoreSlim.Release();
                            });
                        }));
                    }

                    // Wait for all tasks to complete.
                    await Task.WhenAll(tasksWithThrottler.ToArray());
                }
            }
            else
            {
                await Task.WhenAll(enumerable.Select(item => action(item)));
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: A good example of overkilling  asynchrony. And don't call `System.GC.Collect();` in a button click. There are so few reasons to call that manually in this world. If you keep your code simpler probably it will work faster. You don't have to show every change in the ui to the user. Just pop up a spinner do your work and close the spinner.

Comment: The System.GC.Collect() is called only to be sure the time calculation is good and is not influenced by a additional GC due to previous test. I agree with you, it will not be in production code. Also the guidelines from Microsoft write that the status should be updated if the action it expected to take more than 2 sec. In my case the test is for 10 sec in the parallel/quick version and around 24 sec in the non parallel one. So I should provide a visual feedback not just the spinner.

Comment: I tried even to use the [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel?view=netcore-2.2](Parallel Class) but with no luck as I get either random "index out of " error or it returns very early far before all the processes has finished.

Comment: For WhenAll method, it is an async operation, and it will block the UI thread to a certain extent, so the progressbar has this effect unlike foreach. At the same time, its cpu occupancy rate will be very high when use it. If you want to use faster speed, the cpu occupancy rate will be higher. So it's better to create a background task, put your time-consuming operations inside and notify the main interface about the progress.