# Parallel.ForEach memory usage keeps growing

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net-core, parallel.foreach, memory-efficient

```
public string SavePath { get; set; } = @"I:\files\";

public void DownloadList(List<string> list)
{
    var rest = ExcludeDownloaded(list);
    var result = Parallel.ForEach(rest, link=>
    {
        Download(link);
    });
}

private void Download(string link)
{
    using(var net = new System.Net.WebClient())
    {
        var data = net.DownloadData(link);

        var fileName = code to generate unique fileName;
        if (File.Exists(fileName))
            return;

        File.WriteAllBytes(fileName, data);
    }
}

var downloader = new DownloaderService();
var links = downloader.GetLinks();
downloader.DownloadList(links);
```

I observed the usage of RAM for the project keeps growing
[image]

I guess there is something wrong on the Parallel.ForEach(), but I cannot figure it out.

Is there the memory leak, or what is happening?

---

Update 1

After changed to the new code

```
private void Download(string link)
{
    using(var net = new System.Net.WebClient())
    {
        var fileName = code to generate unique fileName;
        if (File.Exists(fileName))
            return;
        var data = net.DownloadFile(link, fileName);
        Track theTrack = new Track(fileName);
        theTrack.Title = GetCDName();
        theTrack.Save();
    }
}
```

[image]

I still observed increasing memory use after keeping running for 9 hours, it is much slowly growing usage though.

Just wondering, is it because that I didn't free the memory use of theTrack file?

Btw, I use [ALT package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/z440.atl.core/3.3.0) for update file metadata, unfortunately, it doesn't implement IDisposable interface.

Comment: It's not necessarily a memory leak, it may must be that the garbage collector hasn't run.

Comment: `File.WriteAllBytes(fileName, data);` Which size of `data` do you have? Have you tried to write by chunks?

Comment: Since you're processing the items parallel, you hold the content of each downloaded file in the memory - multiple at the same time.That's why it increases, especially if they are large files. As @Sean mentioned, the GC most likely hasn't cleaned up yet.

Comment: hi @PavelAnikhouski most of time, the files will be less than 1MB, but it could also be more than 100MB, the biggest so far is 155MB. How to write by chunks?

Comment: Why are you not using `WebClient.DownloadFile()` to directly download to a file?

Comment: @Shawn I have let the program run for more than 1 hour, wouldn't GC run at least once? How to release the content of each downloaded file after it is saved?

Comment: @riQQ DownloadFile() fixed the issue. thanks !

Comment: hi @Shawn you are correct, after I removed the File.WriteAllBytes() and use DownloadFile() directly, my memory leak has gone. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `WebClient.DownloadFile()` to download directly to a file so you don't have the whole file in memory.

Comment: just for curiosity, if I used File.WriteAllBytes(), how could I free its memory after each use?

Comment: @Franva Basically, you're allocating large byte arrays. They are handled specifically by .NET. You can read up more here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/large-object-heap

Comment: `GC.Collect()` frees the memory, if you don't hold any references to the object / byte array anymore.

Answer (score 4):

The [`Parallel.ForEach`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach) method is intended for parallelizing CPU-bound workloads. Downloading a file is an I/O bound workload, and so the `Parallel.ForEach` is not ideal for this case because it needlessly blocks `ThreadPool` threads. The correct way to do it is asynchronously, with async/await. The recommended class for making asynchronous web requests is the [`HttpClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient), and for controlling the level of concurrency an excellent option is the [TPL Dataflow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/dataflow-task-parallel-library) library. For this case it is enough to use the simplest component of this library, the [`ActionBlock`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.actionblock-1) class:

```
async Task DownloadListAsync(List<string> list)
{
    using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
    {
        var rest = ExcludeDownloaded(list);
        var block = new ActionBlock<string>(async link =>
        {
            await DownloadFileAsync(httpClient, link);
        }, new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions()
        {
            MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 10
        });
        foreach (var link in rest)
        {
            await block.SendAsync(link);
        }
        block.Complete();
        await block.Completion;
    }
}

async Task DownloadFileAsync(HttpClient httpClient, string link)
{
    var fileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(); // code to generate unique fileName;
    var filePath = Path.Combine(SavePath, fileName);
    if (File.Exists(filePath)) return;
    var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(link);
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    using (var contentStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
    using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create,
        FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None, 32768, FileOptions.Asynchronous))
    {
        await contentStream.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
    }
}
```

The code for downloading a file with `HttpClient` is not as simple as the `WebClient.DownloadFile()`, but it's what you have to do in order to keep the whole process asynchronous (both reading from the web and writing to the disk).

---

**Caveat:** Asynchronous filesystem operations are currently [not implemented efficiently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63217657/why-file-readalllinesasync-blocks-the-ui-thread/) in .NET. For maximum efficiency it may be preferable to avoid using the `FileOptions.Asynchronous` option in the `FileStream` constructor.

---

**.NET 6 update:** The preferable way for parallelizing asynchronous work is now the [`Parallel.ForEachAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreachasync) API. A usage example can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15136542/parallel-foreach-with-asynchronous-lambda/68901782#68901782).

Comment: There's also `WebClient.DownloadFileAsync`

Comment: @riQQ indeed. But take a look at the [remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient#remarks): *Important - We don't recommend that you use the WebClient class for new development. Instead, use the System.Net.Http.HttpClient class.*

Comment: Interesting, but sadly there's no reason given why they don't recommend the use for new development.

Comment: @riQQ the `HttpClient` is supposed to offer better performance because it reuses connections. This is because you don't have to create a new instance for every request, like you have to do with the `WebClient`.

Comment: beautiful solution with rich explanation, in answer and in comments~!  Great example~! thanks! I will give it a try during lunch break (I started working already >_<;)

Comment: hi @TheodorZoulias I have tried the code, I have not found increase in performance. It is even slower than the Parallel.Foreach().

Comment: @Franva have you experimented with various values for `MaxDegreeOfParallelism`?

Comment: Nope, I only tried with value 50 as I use 50 for Parallel.Foreach() as well, so I want to make sure they are utilizing same number of threads.

Comment: @Franva if you want to make a fair comparison you should add this line before the `Parallel.ForEach` method: `ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(50, 10);`, so that the `ThreadPool` has 50 threads available to execute 50 concurrent web requests. Without this line you are introducing an implicit throttling caused by the starved `ThreadPool`. The outcome of your test indicates that 50 concurrent operations are too many for the remote server to handle, or for the web connection, or for the storage hardware. I suggest that you experiment with a smaller concurrency level. 50 seems to be far from optimal.

Comment: thanks @TheodorZoulias  I will try it and update you. Appreciate your help and explanation. I have learnt insight for the multithreading programming.