# C# Console call rest API 100k plus times in multiprocessing mode (Parallel.ForEach)

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel.foreach

I am using Parallel.ForEach to call a rest api service in batch mode like 1000 request at a time.
My MaxDegreeOfParallelism is set to 1000 , But it seems system only creating 10-15 request at a time althoug system CPU utilization is very normal (15%)

```
var maxDegree = new ParallelOptions() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = MaxDegreeOfParallelism };
        Parallel.ForEach(parsedLines, maxDegree, obj =>
        {


            processIndividualRecord(obj);

            var currentCount = Interlocked.Increment(ref paraaleCounter);
            if (currentCount % 100 == 0)
            {
                logger.Debug("Reaming records to process is:" + (parsedLines.Count - currentCount));
            }
        });
```

Is there any way I can make 1000 request at a time to avoid large wait time in non blocking mode.

Comment: What sane web developer would want you to call their api 1000 at a time ? Additionally the TPL `ForEach` and `For` methods are totally and completely unsuited to this job, you are essentially making a very inefficient threadpool thread blocking tool, as such the task scheduler will take a dim view of these tasks and severely limited your IO work

Comment: You need to research the async and await pattern, why its scalable, and how it benefits IO work

Answer (score 0):

You are running short of `ThreadPool` threads. A quick workaround is to increase the initial pool of workers by using the [`ThreadPool.SetMinThreads`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool.setminthreads) method.

```
ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(1000, 10);
```

A better approach is to call the REST API asynchronously. This way the need for worker threads while the requests are in flight will be removed. An excellent tool for coordinating the asynchronous process is the [TPL Dataflow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/dataflow-task-parallel-library) library. You can see a usage example of this library [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60929044/c-sharp-parallel-foreach-memory-usage-keeps-growing/60930992#60930992).

Comment: Using `Parallel` / TPL for async http (IO) requests is likely overkill. There is no need to spin up those `Task`s.