# How to concurrently complete HTTP calls on an observable collection?

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, async-await, task-parallel-library

In the WPF .net core app there is the following:

- An Observable Collection of items (itemObservCollection).
- A static readonly HttpClient _httpclient
- XML Responses

I am making a URL call to the api on each item in the observable collection (0 to 1000 items in collection). The return is XML. The XML is parsed using XElement. The property values in the observable collection are updated from the XML.

Task.Run is used to run the operation off the UI thread. Parallel.Foreach is used to make the calls in Parallel.

I feel I have made the solution overly complicated. Is there a way to simplify this? UpdateItems() is called from a button click.

```
private async Task UpdateItems()
{
    try
    {
        await Task.Run(() => Parallel.ForEach(itemObservCollection, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 12 }, async item =>
        {
            try
            {
                var apiRequestString = $"http://localhost:6060/" + item.Name;
                HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage = await _httpclient.GetAsync(apiRequestString);
                var httpResponseStream = await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(1024);
                XElement doc = XElement.Load(httpResponseStream);
                foreach (var elem in doc.Descendants())
                {
                    if (elem.Name == "ItemDetails")
                    {
                        var itemUpdate = itemObservCollection.FirstOrDefault(updateItem => updateItem.Name == item.Name);
                        if (itemUpdate != null)
                        {
                            itemUpdate.Price = decimal.Parse(elem.Attribute("Price").Value);
                            itemUpdate.Quantity = int.Parse(elem.Attribute("Quantity").Value);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                LoggerTextBlock.Text = ('\n' + ex.ToString());
            }
        }));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        LoggerTextBlock.Text = ('\n' + ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: It's generally a bad idea to mix Task.Run with Parallel.ForEach.

Comment: `$"http://localhost:6060/" + item.Name;` ?? Why not `$"http://localhost:6060/{item.Name}";` ?

Comment: Using `Parallel.ForEach` with async operations is wrong and actually a bug. `Parallel.ForEach` is meant for *data parallelism* : processing a lot of data using all cores at the same time. It doesn't block, it uses the current thread to process the data. It works by partitioning the data into roughly as many partitions as there are data and feeding each partition to a separate worker thread. Using it with IO operations just blocks the workers without doing anything

Comment: The *serious* bug is that `Parallel.ForEach` doesn't handle asynchronous operations, because it wouldn't make any sense to do so. The lambdas you pass to it are essentially `async void` methods that can't be awaited. This code fires off all almost at the same time and never awaits for them to finish

Comment: What are you trying to do? Throttle multiple HTTP requests? You could do that with eg an ActionBlock with a `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` option set to the number of concurrent operations you want. There shouldn't be any need to use the collection inside the async method

Comment: `Task.Run is used to run the operation off the UI thread.` no, Task.Run is used to run on a *background* thread

Comment: This is most definitely *not* an opinion-based question. The current code is wrong

Comment: @Fildor the answer is simply "yes", that's not an opinion. The problem is just the title. In fact, I suspect there are several duplicate questions that answer the real problem

Comment: Voted to reopen.

Comment: Take a look at this: [How to limit the amount of concurrent async I/O operations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10806951/how-to-limit-the-amount-of-concurrent-async-i-o-operations).

Comment: The `SemaphoreSlim` is sufficient for throttling asynchronous operations, but if you are searching for something more powerful keep in mind the TPL Dataflow library. [`Here`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60929044/c-sharp-parallel-foreach-memory-usage-keeps-growing/60930992#60930992) is an example of using this library for downloading stuff from the web.

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos.I am trying to update the Observable Collection bound to the UI, using new information returned from HttpRequests. I would like to accomplish this as quick as possible, while not blocking the UI thread.

Comment: @Fildor using {item.Name} would likely work as well.

Comment: The consensus seems to be that Task.Run and Parallel.ForEach are incorrect. I will look at TPL Dataflow. Thanks @TheodorZoulias, Fildor, and Panagiotis Kanavos

Comment: @adventuresncode you can't do that with Parallel.ForEach, that's not what it's for. Use an ActionBlock with a DOP of 3.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Curious: Why 3?

Comment: A mistake - the DOP parameter isn't visible. I probably mixed up the value with another question. The DOP could be anything the network or remote servers allow

Comment: This is a call to the localhost so it looks to be all processed on the one pc.  There should be no network latency to speak of.  Have you tried it with just one at a time in a loop.  Call and await response, update then loop for the next?  You don't get multi threading for free and it could be as fast just one at a time. Might even be faster that way.

Comment: @Andy I have tried it one at a time in a loop, however it is much slower.

Comment: While learning how to implement an ActionBlock, @mm8 provided a viable solution with Task.WhenAll. I will try and setup ActionBlocks to complete this task as well. I will update if successful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create an array of tasks and await them all using `Task.WhenAll`.

The following sample code kicks off a task per item in the `ObservableCollection<int>` and then wait asynchronously for all tasks to finish:

```
ObservableCollection<int> itemObservCollection = 
    new ObservableCollection<int>(Enumerable.Range(1, 10));

async Task SendAsync()
{
    //query the HTTP API here...
    await Task.Delay(1000);
}

await Task.WhenAll(itemObservCollection.Select(x => SendAsync()).ToArray());
```

If you want to limit the number of concurrent requests, you could either iterate through a subset of the source collecton to send requests in batches or use a `SemaphoreSlim` to limit the number of actual concurrent requests:

```
Task[] tasks = new Task[itemObservCollection.Count];
using (SemaphoreSlim semaphoreSlim = new SemaphoreSlim(12))
{
    for (int i = 0; i < itemObservCollection.Count; ++i)
    {
        async Task SendAsync()
        {
            //query the HTTP API here...
            try
            {
                await Task.Delay(5000);
            }
            finally
            {
                semaphoreSlim.Release();
            }
        }

        await semaphoreSlim.WaitAsync();
        tasks[i] = SendAsync();
    }
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
```

Comment: There is no throttling here.

Comment: Throttling as in `MaxDegreeOfParallelism`? That's just a matter of iterating through a subset of the source collecton, for example using the `Take` extension method: `itemObservCollection.Take(10)...` `itemObservCollection.Skip(10)` ...

Comment: The OP wants to send requests for every item in the collection, but limit this to 12 concurrently. `Take` wouldn't achieve this.

Comment: `Take(x).Select(_ => SendAsync())` will start `x` tasks. You can then await them and start the next `x` tasks and so on depending on your requirements. This will limit the concurrent number of requests.

Comment: In that case, you would need to wait for all `x` tasks to complete before starting the next batch. A semaphore would be a better solution.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay: I see what you mean. A `SemaphoreSlim` will do the job in this case. I added an example that does not involving creating background tasks using `Task.Run` to my answer.

Comment: await Task.WhenAll solved the problem.  Thank you @mm8