# Using SemaphoreSlim with Parallel.ForEach

Tags: asp.net, multithreading, task-parallel-library, semaphore, parallel.foreach

This is what I am trying to achieve. Let's say I have a process which runs every minute and performs some I/O operations. I want 5 threads to execute simultaneously and do the operations. Suppose if 2 threads took longer than a minute and when the process runs again after a minute, it should execute 3 threads simultaneously as 2 threads are already doing some operations.

So, I used the combination of `SemaphoreSlim` and `Parallel.ForEach`. Please let me know if this is the correct way of achieving this or there is any other better way.

```
private static SemaphoreSlim _semaphoreSlim = new SemaphoreSlim(5);

private async Task ExecuteAsync()
{
    try
    {
        var availableThreads = _semaphoreSlim.CurrentCount;

        if (availableThreads > 0)
        {
            var lists = await _feedSourceService.GetListAsync(availableThreads); // select @top(availableThreads) * from table

            Parallel.ForEach(
                lists,
                new ParallelOptions
                {
                    MaxDegreeOfParallelism = availableThreads
                },
                async item =>
                {
                    await _semaphoreSlim.WaitAsync();

                    try
                    {
                        // I/O operations
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        _semaphoreSlim.Release();
                    }
                });
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.LogError(ex.Message, ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: All code using `async` with `Parallel` is incorrect.

Comment: @StephenCleary would you rather use `await Task.WhenAll(tasks);`?

Comment: @StephenCleary Could you please explain why it is wrong. This would be helpful for understanding

Comment: @ReyanChougle I would look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15136833/7085070)

Comment: @ReyanChougle you still can use Semaphor for throttling

Comment: @OlegI But this will wait for all the tasks to process right? I want to implement in such a way that each thread can exit as soon as it's execution is completed. Could you please show a example if possible

Comment: @ReyanChougle: `Parallel` just doesn't work with `async` methods. Any `async` lambda passed to any `Parallel` method is converted to an `async void`, which [causes many other problems](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Let's say I have a process which runs every minute and performs some I/O operations... Suppose if 2 threads took longer than a minute and when the process runs again after a minute, it should execute 3 threads simultaneously as 2 threads are already doing some operations.

This kind of problem description is somewhat common, but is surprisingly difficult to code correctly. This is because you have a polling-style timer (time based) that is trying to periodically *adjust* a throttling mechanism. Doing this correctly is quite difficult.

So, the first thing I'd recommend is to change the problem description. Consider having the polling mechanism read *all* outstanding work, and then use normal throttling from there (e.g., adding then to an execution-constrained `ActionBlock`).

That said, if you'd prefer continuing down the more complex path, code like this would avoid the `Parallel` with `async` problem:

```
private static SemaphoreSlim _semaphoreSlim = new SemaphoreSlim(5);

private async Task ExecuteAsync()
{
    try
    {
        var availableThreads = _semaphoreSlim.CurrentCount;

        if (availableThreads > 0)
        {
            var lists = await _feedSourceService.GetListAsync(availableThreads); // select @top(availableThreads) * from table

            var tasks = lists.Select(
                async item =>
                {
                    await _semaphoreSlim.WaitAsync();

                    try
                    {
                        // I/O operations
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        _semaphoreSlim.Release();
                    }
                }).ToList();
            await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.LogError(ex.Message, ex);
    }
}
```