# Parallel Foreach loop missing data to bring from nested async method calls

Tags: c#, async-await, parallel.foreach

I am working on C# `Parallel.ForEach` loop. Within the parallel loop, I am calling async method `ProcessMyData` and `ProcessMyData` calling another async method `GetMarkedData` where in `GetMarkedData` method, I am calling the API services to pull record from database via Azure Function API but with parallel loop, I never received data for first thread while this method `GetMarkedData` been called for remaining record and I never receive data in parallel loop however it do work fine in classic loop.

```
Parallel.ForEach(myList, options, async item=>
{
    var processDataList = await ProcessMyData(item.Id);
});

protected async Task<List<myRecord>> ProcessMyData(recordId)
{
    //my code...
 
    var data = await GetMarkedData(recordId);
    // remaining code...
}

public virtual async Task<IEnumerable<Record>> GetMarkedData(recordId id)
{
    using (var myService = HttpClientUtilities...)
    {
        var markedRecordlist = myService.GetData(...)   
    }
}
```

Comment: `Parallel.ForEach` is used for computational purposes not IO, no async here. Use a `List<Task>` in combination with `Task.WhenAll()` or use the Dotnet 6 [`Parallel.ForEachAsync()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreachasync?view=net-6.0)

Comment: There's a duplicate somewhere on SO but I can't find it. The issue is that `Parallel.ForEach` has no overload which takes a `Func<Task>`, so your async lambda gets turned into an `async void`, which means that `Parallel.ForEach` has no idea when it's finished -- so it can't wait for your lambda to complete

Comment: @canton Is this the one you want?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15136542/parallel-foreach-with-asynchronous-lambda

Comment: @Llama That one starts with the asker identifying what the problem is. IIRC there's another one where the answers do a good job of explaining the problem itself, but maybe I'm just making it up. That one will do, anyway -- it has the answer suggesting `ForEachAsync`