# Write an async method with Parallel.Foreach loop that does call another async method to pull record

Tags: c#, async-await, parallel.foreach

I am working on code performance optimizing and need suggestion the best approach in implementing `async` with `parallel.foreach` and/ or `WhenAll`.

The code is split into three main areas.

`Code Definition`

`MethodA` pickup the `Customer` list

`MethodB` `PartA` loop through Customers and pick record from database via a `Azure Function`. this is 1:* relation so 1 customer can have multiple records.

`MethodB` `PartB` go through customer records list that picked in method B Part A and look if is there any files attached. If there is file/ files then it process and send `Customer Reference' back to 'MethodA' where it store record in dictionary. Then it send

### Method A

```
public async Task<List<Customers>> MethodA(){

  List<Customer> customers = await GetAllCustomers();
  var inboundCustomerFiles= new List<InboundCustomerFiles>(); 

   Parallel.ForEach(customer, async customer =>
   {
     var processedCustomer = await MethodB(customer);
     inboundCustomersFiles.AddRange(processedCustomer);

   });
}
```

### Method B

```
  public static async Task<List<InboundCustomerFiles>> MethodB(Customer customer){
     var customerRecord = await GetCustomerRecord(customerId);

     foreach(var customer in customerRecord){
        var files = await getCustomerRecordFile(customerRecordId)
        //...... remaining code
     }
    return inboundCustomerFiles;
  }
```

### Method 3

```
public static async Task<List<InboundCustomerFiles>> GetCustomerRecord(int customerId){
     //API call here that further pull `record` from database
return List<Records>();
}
```

the process in methodB `customerRecord` takes time. How I ensure that it process the data and return to correct customer thread in MethodA. I have tried to use in methodB but it slow down, further I know Parallel.Foreach does not wait so I tried to add `async` reference in lambda expression but not sure A is correct or if is work.

Comment: The `Parallel.ForEach` [is not async-friendly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15136542/parallel-foreach-with-asynchronous-lambda "Parallel foreach with asynchronous lambda").

Comment: can you help me in above customer scenario, I need some guide on that.. many thanks in advanced

Comment: I want to run `Customer` multiple instance, what should I use instead of Parallel>forEach?

Comment: You have explained the relationship between customers and records (one to many), but you haven't explained the relationship those two entities and the "file" entity. Is a file related to a customer or to a record? And what is the relationship between them?

Comment: the file is related to `record` and is `1:*` relationship so 1 record can have 0 or multiple files

Comment: Could you edit the question and include the API that you are using? I suppose that you have three methods, one that fetches customers, one that fetches the records of a customer, and one that fetches the files of a record, correct?

Comment: the customer record and record files are fetch in `MethodB` however in methodB, it call another static method  `GetCustomerRecord() `just to pull record. I have updated the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well for one thing you can pretend that `Parallel.ForEach` awaits your `async` functions, but it doesn't. Instead you want to write something like this:

```cs
   await Task.WhenAll(customers.Select(async customer =>
   {
     var processedCustomer = await MethodB(customer);
     inboundCustomersFiles.AddRange(processedCustomer);
   }));
```

`Task.WhenAll` behaves like `Parallel.ForEach`, but it's awaitable and it also awaits every task you pass to it before completing its own task. Hence when your `await Task.WhenAll` completes, all the inner tasks have completely completed as well.

> the process in methodB customerRecord takes time

That is very ambiguous. If you mean it takes server and/or IO time then that's fine, that's what `async` is for. If you mean it takes *your* CPU time (ie it processes data locally for a long time), then you should spin up a task on a thread pool and await its completion. **Note that this is not necessarily the default thread pool!** Especially if you're writing an ASP.NET (core) application, you want a dedicated thread pool just for this stuff.

Comment: Both batch large amounts of data so you should be fine!