# Job seems to run as Fire and Forget. Database activity continues for up to 10 minutes after success status

Tags: c#, sql-server, multithreading, async-await, hangfire

I am debugging this hangfire service job call and can't figure out why hangfire is reporting a completed state while the stored procedures being called are continuing to run for up to ~10 minutes later. The parallel loop is running a stored procedure against up to 200 databases.

The first image below shows the hangfire status (success in ~40 seconds), meaning the job function completed. The second image shows the Stored Procedures issued form the loop still running for many minutes later. As far as I know, hangfire will report success when the job function completes, report timeout after a max wait, or report error is an exception occurs. I don't see how this function could be exiting in 6 seconds if all tasks are awaited.

Hangfire reports success in 40 seconds
[image: Hangfire Reports success in 40 seconds]

Long Running Query Detection shows queries from the job still running and falling in and out of blocking state many minutes later. The commands starting with --===================== represent the SP running against many different databases.

[image]

Code I have started debugging ->

```
public async Task PerformServiceWork()
{
    try
    {
        var adminDatabases = await _DatabaseService.GetActiveDatabasesAsync();
               
        Parallel.ForEach(adminDatabases,
            new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling((Environment.ProcessorCount * 0.75) * 2.0)) },  // Suggested: MaxDegreeOfParallelism to use a maximum of 75% resources of the system, each processor contains two cores
            async clientDatabase =>
            {
                double elasped = 0.00;
                try
                {
                            
                    var connectionString = _ASettingsHttpApiProvider.GetConnectionString(clientDatabase.SystemName);  

                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(connectionString))
                    {
                        LogHelper.LogInfo(clientDatabase.SystemName, $"Starting at {DateTime.Now:HH:mm:ss.fff tt}");

                        elasped = await UpdateLastDetectedChangeDateAndAlertFlag(clientDatabase, connectionString);

                        LogHelper.LogInfo(clientDatabase.SystemName, $"Ended at {DateTime.Now:HH:mm:ss.fff tt}  Total: {elasped} seconds");
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    LogHelper.LogException(LogLevel.Error, MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod(), clientDatabase.SystemName, ex);
                }

            });

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        LogHelper.LogException(LogLevel.Error, MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod(), "Lease Last Detected Change Job", ex);
    }
}


private async Task<double> UpdateLastDetectedChangeDateAndAlertFlag(tblDatabase clientDatabase, string connectionString)
{
    _ProcessTimer.Restart();

    try
    {
        using var connection = new SqlConnection().AsReducedPoolConnection(clientDatabase, connectionString);
        await connection.ExecuteAsync("AStoredProcedureThatTakesAbout3To5SecondsToRun", commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure, commandTimeout: _CommandTimeOutInSeconds);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        LogHelper.LogException(LogLevel.Error, MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod(), clientDatabase.SystemName, ex);
    }

    _ProcessTimer.Stop();

    return _ProcessTimer.Elapsed.TotalSeconds;
}
```

Comment: Parallel.ForEach should be used when the thing you're doing is CPU bound. In this case it's IO bound because you're waiting on a database. You would be better off using a SemaphoreSlim for throttling I think

Comment: @JoePhillips - Many thanks. I will take that into consideration, for sure. I just need to be able to explain the anomaly right now :/

Comment: This question is basically the same as yours and you'll see that there isn't a great answer because Parallel.ForEach wasn't intended for what you're doing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15136542/parallel-foreach-with-asynchronous-lambda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My thoughts are that `Parallel.ForEach` does not await for the async lambda so `PerformServiceWork` ends before each lambda is still running.

Try to use instead [`Task.WhenAll`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall?view=net-6.0) and await on it.

As I recall `Parallel.ForEach` is more related to Threading while `Tasks` are an abstraction over Threads.