# AsyncEnumerator library not processing collection

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, parallel.foreach, dasync.asyncenumerator

I am using the `AsyncEnumerator` library by @Serge Semenov, and after getting the orders, creating the ConcurrentBag and setting count to 0, nothing happens - can anyone see what's missing here? It never hits the `processedOrders.ToList()` line when debugging.

```
private async Task<List<OrderDto>> ProcessOrderEvents(DateTime cob)
{
    var orders = await _client.GetOrderEvents(cob);

    var processedOrders = new ConcurrentBag<OrderDto>();

    var count = 0;

    await orders.ParallelForEachAsync(async order =>
    {
        var orderDto = new FidessaOrderDto {Cob = cob};
        var orderId = order.Ids.PrimaryId;

        Debug.WriteLine($"Processing OrderId: {orderId} #= {++count}");

        var instrumentDetails = await GetInstrumentDetails(order);

        if (instrumentDetails.Results.Any())
        {
            //...
        }

        var tradeDetails = await _client.GetTrade(tradeId: fill, cob);

        processedOrders.Add(orderDto);
    }, maxDegreeOfParallelism:2);

    return processedOrders.ToList();
}
```

**Update**: Adding Test root.

```
    [TestMethod]
    public async Task Test_20_07_2022()
    {
        var service = new DataService(new ApiClient());

        var data = await service.ProcessData(new DateTime(2022, 07, 20), ReportDataType.Orders);
        
        Assert.AreEqual(920, data.Count);
    }

 public async Task<List<OrderDto>> ProcessData(DateTime cob, 
                                           ReportDataType dataType)
    {
        await PopulateRouteEvents(cob);
        var reportData = new List<OrderDto>();
        if (dataType == ReportDataType.Orders)
            reportData = await ProcessOrderEventsTpl(cob);

        return reportData;
    }
```

Comment: As a side note, the `{++count}` is not thread-safe. The correct is `{Interlocked.Increment(ref count)}`.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @TheodorZoulias.  I am running this from a unit test, I will update the question to show the calls.

Comment: Personally I am not seeing anything in your code that could induce a deadlock. TBH I am not familiar with the inner workings of the [`ParallelForEachAsync`](https://github.com/Dasync/AsyncEnumerable/blob/49ff1de41cc818f6aa099ad646c600d950a6d79c/src/Extensions/ParallelForEachExtensions.cs#L173) extension method though. From a quick look, I can see that it violates the [CA2008](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca2008) guideline, so it's probably not a top notch piece of software. Have you considered switching to the `Parallel.ForEachAsync`?

Comment: Thanks again for the feedback @TheodorZoulias, I will revert back to `ForEachAsync`, and solve that :)