# Parallel.ForEach is not updating the Windows form UI

Tags: c#, winforms, concurrency, parallel.foreach

I have an windows form, where I can enter the number of records to create at once. If I mention to create 1 million records, it takes more time using a single thread using for loop. So I'm trying to create these 1 million records in a batch of 100/10 (configurable) using `Parallel.ForEach`. While the operation is in progress, I'm trying to update the progress in the UI textbox (like showing many records completed). But the problem is, till before calling the `Parallel.ForEach` progress status textbox is updating but within the `Parallel.ForEach` operation, UI element is not updating. Once after finishing the `Parallel.ForEach` only its updating.

```
public partial class CreateRecordsForm : Form
{
    private void CreateRecordsBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.progressStatusTxt.Text = "Started Creating Records"; //Updating in UI
        int count = 0;
        await Task.Run(() => Parallel.ForEach(bulkCreateRequests, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = parallelThreadsSizeInt }, request =>
         {
             dataservice.CreateRecords(request);
             Interlocked.Increment(ref count);
             string progressStatus = count + " of " + bulkCreateRequests.Count + " Requests Completed";
             this.progressStatusTxt.Text = progressStatus; //NOT updating in UI
         }));
        await Task.WhenAll();
        this.progressStatusTxt.Text = "Finished Creating Records"; //Updating in UI
    }
}
```

I have tried by creating a delegate to update the UI but still not working.

```
public delegate void BulkOrderCreateFormDelegate(string status);
//...
public BulkOrderCreateFormDelegate BulkOrderCreateFormCallback;
//...
BulkOrderCreate()
{
    this.BulkOrderCreateFormCallback += new BulkOrderCreateFormDelegate(this.SetProgressStatusValueFn);
}
private void SetProgressStatusValueFn(string progressStatusValue)
{
    if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(progressStatusValue))
        this.progressStatusTxt.Text = progressStatusValue;
}
private void CreateRecordsBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.progressStatusTxt.Text = "Started Creating Records"; //Updating in UI
    int count = 0;
    await Task.Run(() => Parallel.ForEach(bulkCreateRequests, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = parallelThreadsSizeInt }, request =>
     {
         dataservice.CreateRecords(request);
         Interlocked.Increment(ref count);
         string progressStatus = count + " of " + bulkCreateRequests.Count + " Requests Completed";
         BulkOrderCreateFormCallback(progressStatus); //Getting error : Cross thread operation
     }));
    await Task.WhenAll();
    this.progressStatusTxt.Text = "Finished Creating Records"; //Updating in UI
}
```

Is anyone know how to do this? Can you refer me to a sample working code?

Comment: Did you try after `this.progressStatusTxt.Text = progressStatus;` add new line `this.progressStatusTxt.Refresh();` ?
btw. I think is better use `Label` for this than `TextBox`, just my personal opinion.

Comment: winforms runs in a "primary" thread by default, if you want to update the UI from a different thread you need to call Dispatcher.Invoke or Dispatcher.BeginInvoke

Comment: what `await Task.WhenAll();` does in here?

Comment: Related, but not a problem, Parallel.ForEach will automatically run in a separate thread (probably) which is all managed behind the scenes. That is, you don't need to pass through to Task.Run unless you want the `await`. If .NET 6 is an option, Parallel.ForEachAsync was added" https://stackoverflow.com/a/68901782/1462295

Comment: @BurnsBA the `Parallel.ForEachAsync` is intended for parallelizing asynchronous work. This is not the case here. The OP has synchronous work to do, and they only want to offload it on the `ThreadPool` in order to keep the UI responsive.

Comment: @BurnsBA: WinForms doesn't use `Dispatcher` (as does WPF).  Instead, the base Form class and all the control classes inherit from `Control` and it has an `InvokeRequired` property, as well as the `Invoke` and `BeginInvoke` (and `EndInvoke`) methods.  When used correctly, the `BackgroundWorker` class is able to marshal state and UI-updating properly from background threads to the UI thread

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For reporting progress you can use the [`Progress<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.progress-1) class and the [`IProgress<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iprogress-1) interface. It is important to instantiate the `Progress<T>` class on the UI thread, because it captures the current `SynchronizationContext` during its instantiation, and uses the captured context to propagate the progress messages.

```
public partial class CreateRecordsForm : Form
{
    private async void CreateRecordsBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IProgress<string> progress = new Progress<string>(
            message => this.progressStatusTxt.Text = message);
        progress.Report("Started Creating Records");
        int count = 0;
        ParallelOptions options = new() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = parallelThreadsSizeInt };
        await Task.Run(() => Parallel.ForEach(bulkCreateRequests, options, request =>
        {
            dataservice.CreateRecords(request);
            int localCount = Interlocked.Increment(ref count);
            string progressStatus = localCount + " of " +
                bulkCreateRequests.Count + " Requests Completed";
            progress.Report(progressStatus);
        }));
        progress.Report("Finished Creating Records");
    }
}
```

The UI controls are affine to the UI thread. They are supposed to be manipulated exclusively on this thread.