# Parallel when use with puppeteer

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, puppeteer

This is my code. If i use forEach normally my code don't have any problem but when i replace by Parallel.ForEach it can't open url at line  await page.GoToAsync(url);
What should i do. Thank you

```
Parallel.ForEach(Urls, async url =>
{
    Uri uri = new Uri(url);
    var myDomain = uri.Host;
    var objectDomain = domains.FirstOrDefault(item => item.Domain == myDomain);
    var price = objectDomain.Price;
    var oldPrice = objectDomain.oldPrice;
    var page = await browser.NewPageAsync();
    await page.GoToAsync(url);
    var priceNode = await page.QuerySelectorAsync($".{price}");
    var oldPriceNode = await page.QuerySelectorAsync($".{oldPrice}");
}
```

I try move line "var page = await browser.NewPageAsync();" out of for loop but i still can't take data from web.
I'm trying to increase performance when use puppeteer. 3s for 1 link is too long

Comment: I don't know if it's relevant, but the `Parallel.ForEach` [is not async friendly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15136542/parallel-foreach-with-asynchronous-lambda "Parallel foreach with asynchronous lambda").

Comment: So if i need increase performance for puppeteer what should do i instead of parallel

Comment: It's not just that `Parallel.ForEach` doesn't work with async code. You're controlling the *browser* through *Node.js*. You need a different worker per task, not just a new tab.  Why puppeteer instead of its evolution in .NET, Playwright? Playwright supports parallel tests in NUnit out of the box. Internally, it does use separate BrowserService/worker instances, storing them in a pool for reuse

Comment: @Long what are you trying to do in the first place? Run tests in parallel or scrape sites in parallel? In NUnit or MSTest you could inherit from [Playwright's PageTest](https://playwright.dev/dotnet/docs/test-runners#running-nunit-tests-in-parallel) class and have it create new workers as needed. In your screen scraping application you'd have to create the workers yourself.

Comment: Ok thank you i will test PlayWright, i fixed my code above.

Comment: In case you have found a solution to your problem, you can post it as a [self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Embedding an answer inside the body of the question is frowned upon here.

Answer (score 0):

`Parallel.ForEach` doesn't work with asynchronous delegates. What you wrote is essentially an `async void` method that starts a browser but never waits for the script to finish. This code will create N tabs and terminate before even the first navigation completes.

It's not enough to switch to `Parallel.ForEachAsync` either. You need to create multiple "browser" instances. Puppeteer and Playwright are written in Node.js, which means `browser` is actually a single-threaded Node.js worker. While each browser can use multiple tabs, you can only send one command at a time to it.

If you want to accelerate NUnit or MSTest tests, a good option would be to switch to Playwright and [use its PageTest base class](https://playwright.dev/dotnet/docs/test-runners#running-nunit-tests-in-parallel). Both Puppeteer Sharp and Playwright Sharp were created by the same person but Playwright is a "bit" more popular.

PageTest's parent types create and pool multiple workers that are shared among tests. By default, NUnit runs multiple files in parallel. You can run multiple tests in the same file in parallel simply by changing an attribute:

```
[Parallelizable(ParallelScope.All)]
[TestFixture]
public class MyTest : PageTest
{
    [Test]
    public async Task TestLogin()
    {

        await Page.GotoAsync("/login");
    }

    [Test]
    public async Task TestIndex()
    {

        await Page.GotoAsync("/Index");
    }

    ...
}
```

In this example each test method will run in parallel, each one getting its own worker and Page object