# Async background workers are broken

Tags: c#, .net-core, async-await

I have a background worker method that does some jobs step by step.  However, when I converted all work to async I saw that a lot of steps weren't complete, there were no logs, no alerts. The code was broken but there is no information in the log panel about how and where.

All methods work inside `try ... catch` and all steps log a success or fail message.  The Sync version works correctly. It completes all jobs and steps. But the Async is not. It skips some jobs and some steps... there is no information about what happened.

Does anyone have an idea about this issue?

Here is an example of my code.

```
public class BackgroudWorker
{
    public async Task<int> StartWorker()
    {
         await Task.Run(async () => {
            await StartParallel();
         });
        return 0;
    }

    public async Task<int> StartParallel()
    {
        //hundreds of jobs
        List<int>  jobList = new List<int>(){1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9};
        
        Parallel.ForEach(jobList, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 24 }, async job =>
        {
           string content = await DownloadDataContentAsync(job);
            if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(content)){
                var list = await DeserializeContentAsync(content);
                var dbSuccess = await SaveToDbAsync(list);
                var fileSuccess = await SaveFileSystemAsync(list);
            }
          
        });
        
        await Console.Error.WriteAsync("");
        return 5;
    }
    
    public async Task<string> DownloadDataContentAsync(object job)
    {
        try
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            using HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("http://www.contoso.com/");
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            return responseBody;
        }
        catch (HttpRequestException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nException DownloadDataContentAsync!");
            Console.WriteLine("Message :{0} ", e.Message);
        }
        return "";
    }

    public async Task<List<object>> DeserializeContentAsync(string content)
    {
        //Deserialize staff and return object
        
        //this is just for await
        await Console.Error.WriteAsync("");
        return new List<object>();
    }

    public async Task<bool> SaveToDbAsync(List<object> list)
    {
        try
        {
            //Database save operation
        }
        catch (HttpRequestException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nException SaveToDbAsync!");
            Console.WriteLine("Message :{0} ", e.Message);
        }
        //this is just for await
        await Console.Error.WriteAsync("");
        return true;
    }

    public async Task<bool> SaveFileSystemAsync(List<object> list)
    {
        try
        {
            //convert data to csv and save to file system
        }
        catch (HttpRequestException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nException SaveFileSystemAsync!");
            Console.WriteLine("Message :{0} ", e.Message);
        }
        //this is just for await
        await Console.Error.WriteAsync("");
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: `dbSuccess = SaveToDbAsync(list);` - did you miss an `await` there?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parallel foreach with asynchronous lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15136542/parallel-foreach-with-asynchronous-lambda) You need `Parallel.ForEachAsync` otherwise it doesn't work with `async`

Comment: More notes: use a global `HttpClient` as it is thread-safe. `SaveToDbAsync` and `SaveFileSystemAsync` missing `await`. Why use `Task.Run`, what does it gain you?

Comment: The `Parallel.ForEach` is not async-friendly.

Comment: @Charlieface I tried `Parallel.ForEachAsync` but not work. I forgot `await ` in the sample code but in the real code, there is no await problem.  I must use `Task.Run` because the worker called by APIs.

Comment: Shouldn't `if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(content))` be `if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(content))` -negating?

Comment: Then show that code. I think you have cut out too much of the original. Also "I must use Task.Run because the worker called by APIs." makes no sense; if those APIs can use `await` then they won't have a problem with it being called directly, and if they can't handle it then `Task.Run` won't help.

Comment: The fact that C# allows implicit casting from `Func<T, Task>` to `Action<T>` allows these mistakes to occur. It's one of worst mistakes they made.